# Web spider on prices

Tags: php, offset, preg-match-all, web-crawler

I would like to compare certain products by price on a couple of websites.
So I can create a price history for myself before buying a product.
If the price stays stable, I usually order the product, if not I go and ask questions why the price keeps going up and down.

I wanted to program a web-crawler for myself using PHP so this is done automatically as it would take allot of time when I do it manually.

So I created a MySql database where I input all the URL's from all the products I want to follow.
After that I use i simple script to output the prices:

```
<?php

@ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'salesrep';
$dbpass = 'pas';
$dbname = "spider";
$dbtable = "price_compair";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbtable");
mysql_close($conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['artikel'] . "</td>";
    if ($row['url_site1'] == "") {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    } else {
        if (!$fp = fopen($row['url_tx3'], "r")) {
            return false;
        }
        $content = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $content .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        preg_match_all("/\&euro; (\d+\.\d+)/", $content, $pricesite1, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $replace1 = array("&euro; ");
        echo "<td>" . str_replace($replace1, "", $pricesite1[1][0]) . "</td>";
    }

    if ($row['url_site2'] == "") {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    } else {
        if (!$fp = fopen($row['url_tx3shop'], "r")) {
            return false;
        }
        $content = "";
        if (ob_get_level() == 0)
            ob_start();
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $content .= fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+\,\d+|(\d+\,\d+)/", $content, $pricesite2, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $replace2 = array("€ ", ".");
        $out = str_replace(",", ".", str_replace($replace2, "", $pricesite2[1][0]));
        if ($out == "") {
            echo "<td>" . str_replace(",", ".", str_replace($replace2, "", $pricesite2[0][0])) . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>" . $out . "</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
?>
```

The main problem I came across was that 1 website uses the € sign, the other one handles € in the code, so finding the price is tricky.
Also, the euro sign could be in front or behind the price.
And to make it more difficult, there could be a recommended retail price before the actual price.

My script works at the moment, but the code I use for the preg_match_all is far from perfect.
Is there anyone the has an idea on how to build it up so it practically works perfect on any website?

Also, is the fgets statement I use a correct way on building the spider?

I know that there are comparison website out there that do this for me, but I find it to be a fun PHP project :)

Comment: Good lord, please indent your code.

Comment: "perfect on any website?" No.

Comment: PHP might not be your best tool for this. [NoodleJS](http://noodlejs.com/) makes it easy for you to create rules in JSON format that can be loaded on a website-by-website basis, making it much easier to target the DOM with the price in it.

Comment: You may find that you'll need to find prices by their HTML location, rather than what they look like. Even if you can correctly find Euro amounts, single product pages often have a "alternative products" sidebar, which also have prices on them. So, if you can use a scraping system that supports CSS selectors, you'll find this task a lot easier. Also, be prepared to write rules on a per-site basis, so make your system amenable to adding new rules in a few minutes.

Comment: You'll need to create code specific to where and how the price appears on each site.

Answer (score 1):

I only have a solution to one of your issues. What you are asking is going to be very difficult - a script that can understand what of many prices on any page may be refering to that specific product of that page. You need to write code for each site. I think this will be a waste of time, as if you a scraping 20 sites, it is likely at least one will change their HTML per year.

Anyway, for the HTML entity (€) issue, pass all the HTML though:

```
function entitiesToUTF8( $str )
{
    $str = preg_replace( '~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'entityToUTF8("\\1")', $str );
    $str = preg_replace( '~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'entityToUTF8(\\1)', $str );

    return $str;
}
```

and this will convert HTML entities to characters.